# How do I fix a ValueError: read of closed file exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

This simple **Python 3** script:

```
import urllib.request

host = "scholar.google.com"
link = "/scholar.bib?q=info:K7uZdMSvdQ0J:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&hl=en&as_sdt=1,14&ct=citation&cd=0"
url = "http://" + host + link
filename = "cite0.bib"
print(url)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

raises this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ricardo\Desktop\Google-Scholar\BibTex\test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 150, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1597, in retrieve
    block = fp.read(bs)
ValueError: read of closed file
```

I thought this might be a temporary problem, so I added some simple exception handling like so:

```
import random
import time
import urllib.request

host = "scholar.google.com"
link = "/scholar.bib?q=info:K7uZdMSvdQ0J:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&hl=en&as_sdt=1,14&ct=citation&cd=0"
url = "http://" + host + link
filename = "cite0.bib"
print(url)
while True:
    try:
        print("Downloading...")
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 5))
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

but this just prints `Downloading...` ad infinitum.

Comment: If you look in `http://scholar.google.com/robots.txt` you can see that Google forbids automated downloads of this page. And if you try using `wget` you will get a `403 Forbidden` error. I suspect this is also happening to your script.

Comment: @senderle There isn't an API, so I'm parsing it manually.

Comment: @senderle, most likely you need to send a cookie to get the content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your URL return a 403 code error and apparently [urllib.request.urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) is not good at detecting all the HTTP errors, because it's using [`urllib.request.FancyURLopener`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.FancyURLopener) and this latest try to swallow error by returning an `urlinfo` instead of raising an error.

About the fix if you still want to use [urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) you can override FancyURLopener like this (code included to also show the error):

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import FancyURLopener


class FixFancyURLOpener(FancyURLopener):

    def http_error_default(self, url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers):
        if errcode == 403:
            raise ValueError("403")
        return super(FixFancyURLOpener, self).http_error_default(
            url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers
        )

# Monkey Patch
urllib.request.FancyURLopener = FixFancyURLOpener

url = "http://scholar.google.com/scholar.bib?q=info:K7uZdMSvdQ0J:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&hl=en&as_sdt=1,14&ct=citation&cd=0"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "cite0.bib")
```

Else and this is what **i recommend** you can use [`urllib.request.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) like so:

```
fp = urllib.request.urlopen('http://scholar.google.com/scholar.bib?q=info:K7uZdMSvdQ0J:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&hl=en&as_sdt=1,14&ct=citation&cd=0')
with open("citi0.bib", "w") as fo:
    fo.write(fp.read())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. +1 and the accept for the monkey patching and general help, even though I've since realised, per the comments above,that `robots.txt` disallows downloading those files. I completely forgot to check that.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your app over managed cloud infrastructure, or managed security service, check for limitations that may come from them. Happened to me. Cloud providers sometimes impose a white list on accessible sites.