# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file with urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I have a problem scraping data from a seekingalpha website. I know this question has been asked several times so far but the solutions provided didn't help

I have the following block of code:

```
class AppURLopener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0"


def scrape_news(url, source):
    opener = AppURLopener()
    if(source=='SeekingAlpha'):
        print(url)
        with opener.open(url) as response:
            s = response.read()
            data = BeautifulSoup(s, "lxml")
            print(data)

scrape_news('https://seekingalpha.com/news/3364386-apple-confirms-hiring-waymo-senior-engineer','SeekingAlpha')
```

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

EDIT:
whole traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\news.py", line 107, in <module>
    scrape_news('https://seekingalpha.com/news/3364386-apple-confirms-hiring-waymo-senior-engineer','SeekingAlpha')
  File ".\news.py", line 83, in scrape_news
    with opener.open(url) as response:
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\response.py", line 30, in __enter__
    raise ValueError("I/O operation on closed file")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: can you put all your traceback?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531617/how-do-i-fix-a-valueerror-read-of-closed-file-exception Your request returns a 403.

Answer (score 2):

Your URL returns a 403. Try this in your terminal to confirm:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" https://seekingalpha.com/news/3364386-apple-confirms-hiring-waymo-senior-engineer
```

Or, try this in your Python repl:

```
import urllib.request

url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/news/3364386-apple-confirms-hiring-waymo-senior-engineer'
opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener()
response = opener.open(url)

print(response.getcode())
```

`FancyURLOpener` is swallowing any errors about the failure response code, which is why your code continues to the `response.read()` instead of exiting, even though it hasn't recorded a valid response. The standard `urllib.request.urlopen` should handle this for you by throwing an exception on a 403 error, otherwise you can handle it yourself.